# Nativescript Vue: SearchBar on Android in focus with keyboard visible when page loads

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

In Android, the page loads with the keyboard expanded and the focus is on the search bar.

I am trying to keep the focus from not being there on page load.  The relevant code is :

```html
    <StackLayout height="100%" 
                         class="main-container" 
                         >
        <SearchBar ref="searchBars" 
                  class="search-bar" 
                  @loaded="onSearchLoaded($event)" 
                  @textChange="onTextChanged($event)"/>
```

I have tried adding:

```html
       mounted() {
          this.$refs.searchBars.nativeView.dismissSoftInput();
       }
```

but this has not worked.  I also tried adding  `this.$refs.searchBars.nativeView.dismissSoftInput()`
to the `@loaded` event function of the searchBar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<SearchBar @loaded="onSearchBarLoaded($event)"  />
```

And add a method:

```
onSearchBarLoaded: function(event) {
    if (event.object.android) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            event.object.dismissSoftInput();
            event.object.android.clearFocus();
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried the above method and failed. So I've did a small trick to tackle the situation.
I've added a dummy search bar and set the visibility to hidden. So the focus will shift to the dummy search bar! Here is my code.

```
<SearchBar 
v-model="searchPhrase"
@textChange="onSearch" 
@submit="onSearch"
backgroundColor="white" 
@clear="clearSearch"  />

<!--Dummy searchbar -->
<SearchBar v-show="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method to focus on what ever you want.

```js
searchBars() {
      this.$refs.searchBars.nativeView.focus();
    },
```